# Rails 5 integration test converts fixture_file_upload to string

Tags: testing, ruby-on-rails-5

**Env**
Rails: 5.1.3
Ruby: 2.3.1p112

**Context**
I have a basic integration test as follows:

```
class MerchandisesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def test_successful_create
    post org_merchandises_path(org, merchandise: merchandise_params)

    ...
  end

  def merchandise_params
    {
      description: 'Get swole fast.',
      name: 'Foo Powder',
      price: 50,
      images_attributes: {
        '0' => {
          image:   fixture_file_upload('files/image.png', 'image/png'),
          primary: true,
        }
      }
    }
  end
end
```

When I run the test, the image param gets converted to a `String`:

```
# Inside MerchandisesController#create

params.dig(:merchandise, :images_attributes, '0', :image)
=> "#<Rack::Test::UploadedFile:0x007fbdc9520b00>"
# This is a String, but should instance of ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile
```

**Possible Related Issues**
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28129

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, using the post method in the following manner does not properly serialize/deserialize the image param:

```
# Fails to properly serialize file param
post org_merchandises_path(org, merchandise: merchandise_params)
```

You have to do this:

```
# Properly serializes the file param
post org_merchandises_path(org), params: { merchandise: merchandise_params }
```

I have no idea why. Seems like it should work both ways, but it doesn't.